# Hide content from non-fans in a Facebook *IFrame*

Tags: facebook, iframe

There was a previous question asked about this but I have never found a solution, I am using the below code but it never, ever works:

```
<?php

$request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];

list($encoded_sig, $load) = explode('.', $request, 2);

$fbData = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($load, '-_', '+/')), true);

if (!empty($fbData["page"]["liked"]))

{ ?>

NON FAN STUFF

<?php } else { ?>

FAN STUFF

<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it the *other* way around!

It should be, if it's empty => not a fan
The way you are doing it now is: if it's **NOT** empty => not a fan!!

Please review my [tutorial](http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/determine-if-the-user-likes-fan-of-your-page-when-landing-on-your-page-tab/29/):

```
<?php
$signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];
list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2);
$data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);

if (empty($data["page"]["liked"])) {
    echo "You are not a fan!";
} else {
    echo "Welcome back fan!";
}
?>
```

Comment: I actually figured it out otherwise, I needed to add 'www' to all my URL's so the JSON could communicate back and forth *whew*

Answer (score 0):

The code works for an app which is an iframe loaded in a Page tab.